# How to set the default mimetype to render in VSCode Jupyter Notebook

Tags: jupyter-notebook, jupyter, visual-studio-code

How can i change the default mimetype to render in a Jupyter Notebook inside VSCode?

[image: example]

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 3):

Suppose you want to make Jupyter use "text/plain" as renderer default.

**Step 1**: in the output cell, choose text/plain

**Step 2**: Open the Command Palette (<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>P</kbd> or <kbd>Cmd</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>P</kbd> on Mac), search for "mime" and click: "Notebook: Save Mimetype Display Order"

**Step 3**: You will be prompted to choose either to enable that default setting globally (choose "User Settings") or locally for that specific workspace (choose "Workspace Settings")

[Notebook: Save Mimetype Display Order](https://i.stack.imgur.com/f2hFz.png)